# How do I export part of an XML file to a multi-level DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to export part of an XML file to a multi-level DataFrame because I find it more convenient to work with. An exemple of the file would be :

```xml
<file filename="stack_example" created="today">
    <unit time="day" volume="cm3" surface="cm2"/>
    <zone z_id="10">
        <surfacehistory type="calculation">
            <surfacedata time-begin="1" time-end="2">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.256</location>
                    <location l-identity="45"> 2.3</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="3">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.6</location>
                    <location l-identity="4"> 2.5</location>
                    <location l-identity="17"> 2.4</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
            <surfacedata time-begin="2" time-end="3">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="78"> 3.2</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="5">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.7</location>
                    <location l-identity="7"> 4.5</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
        </surfacehistory>
    </zone>
</file>
```

The ideal output from this example would be a Pandas Dataframe similar to this :

```
time-begin  time-end     thing  location    surface
         1         2         1         2      1,256
                                      45        2,3
                             3         2        1,6
                                       4        2,5
                                      17        2,4
         2         3         1        78        3,2
                             5         2        1,7
                                       7        4,5
```

Here is the current code I wrote :

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

datas = open("stack_example.xml","r")
doc = BeautifulSoup(datas.read(), "lxml")
doc.unit.get("surface")

l = []
temp={}

surfacedatas = doc.surfacehistory.find_all("surfacedata")
for surfacedata in surfacedatas:
    time_begin = surfacedata.get("time-begin")
    time_end = surfacedata.get("time-end")

    temp["time_begin"]=[time_begin]
    temp["time_end"]=[time_end]

    things = surfacedata.find_all("thing", recursive=False)
    for thing in thingss:
        identity = thing.get("identity")
        temp["thing"]=[identity]
 
        locations = thing.find_all("location", recursive=False)
        for location in locations:
            l_identity = location.get("l-identity")
            surface = location.getText()
            temp["surface"]=[surface]
            temp["location"]=[l_identity]
        l.append(pd.DataFrame(temp))
        
res = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True).fillna(0.)
```

It only gets the last **location** of all **things** because the location gets refreshed in the loop, but I'm not sure on how to achieve desired result from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `lxml`, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, and the recent IO module, [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) introduced in v1.3. While this method works on flat XML files by default, its `stylesheet` argument allows you to transform the raw input to flatter format for data frame migration.

Specifically, XSLT parses down to the `<location>` nodes and pull parent and ancestor attributes as siblings for flatter structure with repeated nodes.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
   <xsl:template match="/file">
     <data>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::location"/>
     </data>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="location">
     <row>
       <time_begin><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::surfacedata/@time-begin"/></time_begin>
       <time_end><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::surfacedata/@time-end"/></time_end>
       <thing><xsl:value-of select="parent::thing/@identity"/></thing>
       <location><xsl:value-of select="@l-identity"/></location>
       <surface><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></surface>
     </row>
   </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dVc)</kbd>

**Python** *(no other packages needed)*

```py
import pandas as pd

xml_file = "input.xml"
xsl_file = "style.xsl"

surface_data_df = pd.read_xml(xml_file, stylesheet=xsl_file)

surface_data_df
#    time_begin  time_end  thing  location  surface
# 0           1         2      1         2    1.256
# 1           1         2      1        45    2.300
# 2           1         2      3         2    1.600
# 3           1         2      3         4    2.500
# 4           1         2      3        17    2.400
# 5           2         3      1        78    3.200
# 6           2         3      5         2    1.700
# 7           2         3      5         7    4.500
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly have it. Just slightly altered the logic a bit. But looks right.

```
datas = '''<file filename="stack_example" created="today">
    <unit time="day" volume="cm3" surface="cm2"/>
    <zone z_id="10">
        <surfacehistory type="calculation">
            <surfacedata time-begin="1" time-end="2">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.256</location>
                    <location l-identity="45"> 2.3</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="3">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.6</location>
                    <location l-identity="4"> 2.5</location>
                    <location l-identity="17"> 2.4</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
            <surfacedata time-begin="2" time-end="3">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="78"> 3.2</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="5">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.7</location>
                    <location l-identity="7"> 4.5</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
        </surfacehistory>
    </zone>
</file>'''
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

#datas = open("stack_example.xml","r")
#doc = BeautifulSoup(datas.read(), "lxml")
doc = BeautifulSoup(datas, "lxml")
doc.unit.get("surface")

rows = []
surfacedatas = doc.surfacehistory.find_all("surfacedata")
for surfacedata in surfacedatas:
    row = {}
    time_begin = surfacedata.get("time-begin")
    time_end = surfacedata.get("time-end")

    row = {'time-begin':time_begin,
         'time-end':time_end}


    things = surfacedata.find_all("thing", recursive=False)
    for thing in things:
        identity = thing.get("identity")
        row.update({'thing':identity})
        
        locations = thing.find_all("location", recursive=False)
        for location in locations:
            locationStr = location['l-identity']   
            surface = location.text.strip()
            
            row.update({'location':locationStr,
                        'surface':surface})
            
            row_copy = row.copy()
            rows.append(row_copy)
            
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
  time-begin time-end thing location surface
0          1        2     1        2   1.256
1          1        2     1       45     2.3
2          1        2     3        2     1.6
3          1        2     3        4     2.5
4          1        2     3       17     2.4
5          2        3     1       78     3.2
6          2        3     5        2     1.7
7          2        3     5        7     4.5
```

Comment: The output is not a multi-level DataFrame, but it didn't have to be. This answer helped me capture all the info I need to analyse them. Thank you !

Comment: ah ya. Didn't catch that in the question that you wanted multi level. I'm sure you could do a groupby if you really needed it to be

Answer (score 1):

You could set the index based on columns:

```
df.set_index(df.columns.to_list())
```

Take a look at some issues in your code:

- There is a typo in `for thing in thingss:`
- Instead of `temp["location"]=[identity]` set `temp["thing"]=[identity]`
- Change position to get correct order of columns

  ```
  temp["surface"]=[surface]
  temp["location"]=[l_identity]
  ```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''
<file filename="stack_example" created="today">
    <unit time="day" volume="cm3" surface="cm2"/>
    <zone z_id="10">
        <surfacehistory type="calculation">
            <surfacedata time-begin="1" time-end="2">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.256</location>
                    <location l-identity="45"> 2.3</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="3">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.6</location>
                    <location l-identity="4"> 2.5</location>
                    <location l-identity="17"> 2.4</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
            <surfacedata time-begin="2" time-end="3">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="78"> 3.2</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="5">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.7</location>
                    <location l-identity="7"> 4.5</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
        </surfacehistory>
    </zone>
</file>
'''

doc = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")


l = []
temp = {}

surfacedatas = doc.surfacehistory.find_all("surfacedata")
for surfacedata in surfacedatas:
    time_begin = surfacedata.get("time-begin")
    time_end = surfacedata.get("time-end")

    temp["time_begin"]=[time_begin]
    temp["time_end"]=[time_end]

    things = surfacedata.find_all("thing", recursive=False)
    for thing in things:
        identity = thing.get("identity")
        temp["thing"]=[identity]
 
        locations = thing.find_all("location", recursive=False)
        for location in locations:
            l_identity = location.get("l-identity")
            surface = location.getText()
            temp["location"]=[l_identity]
            temp["surface"]=[surface]
            l.append(pd.DataFrame(temp))

df = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True).fillna(0.)
df.set_index(df.columns.to_list())
```

Comment: you are right about the typo in my example which I corrected. I kept the order the order the same though because it is a part of your answer to the question.